FT230X using USB-C receptacle not working for data transfer
I have tried to add a USB-C connection to my PCBA solely for data transfer.
I have used a FT230XQ-R microchip (Datasheet) and followed their uploaded example for a USB-C receptacle. I have now received the PCB and when I plug it in - my laptop does not register it as a port when I check the device manager. I have no idea why it is not working... Maybe by glimpsing over my schematic maybe you can see what the issue is, as I am quite new to electronics and could have done a stupid mistake...
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you :)



At least you did not wire it correctly for self-powered mode. That should not affect the PC being able to detect it though, but I don't know if it does. Have you tried first connecting it to the PC and then turn on the 3.3V supply?

Have you read the chip errata? Do you happen to have rev B silicon or which revision you have?

@Justme Thank you for your replies. I checked some more schematics of the FT230XQ chip and I see that for some reason I have connected the TXD to RX and not the other way around. Do you think that might influence the pc not detecting the pcb?

Of course not, because FTDI TXD output must go to MCU RXD input. Please check your chip silicon revision printed on it. Also the problem may be elsewhere in the schematics, not in the parts you show.

Since you are making a self powered device, you need to wire it up in a self powered way.
You need to configure one of the configurable pins into the VBUS_SENSE mode and the power descriptor should be set to zero
Section 6.2 of the datasheet of the FT230X shows an example of such a configuration. Note the resistors on VBUS going to the pin you configured as VBUS_Sense, so the chip can detect if VBUS is present before activating its pull up resistor on the D+ line to identify as an USB 2.0 device. Failing to do so make some hosts reject your device
